# Javafx: custom checkbox treetablecell doesn't commit the changes

Tags: javafx-2, treetablecelleditor

I'm trying to create my custom `TreeTable` `CellFactory` using `CheckBox`, I know there is a default CellFactory called `CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn()`, but I want to use my custom cellFactory so I can do somethings after clicking on the `CheckBox`.
So, my problem is that when I click on the checkbox and call `commitEdit()` to save the chagnes into the cell it doesn't work !
Here is my custom cellFactory class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import smt.tsk.model.Task;

public class CheckboxCellFactory extends TreeTableCell<Task, Boolean>{
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public CheckboxCellFactory() {
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("clicked: "+checkBox.isSelected());
                //---I called this here to save changes into the cell after clicking on the CheckBox
                commitEdit(checkBox.isSelected());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }else{
            checkBox.setSelected(item);
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

And simply I applied the cellFactory to my column like this:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<Task,Boolean>, TreeTableCell<Task,Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<Task, Boolean> call(TreeTableColumn<Task, Boolean> e) {
                return new CheckboxCellFactory();
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just have to update the object, in my case `Task`, that exists inside `TreeTableRow` like this:

```
checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                boolean c = checkBox.isSelected();
                TreeTableRow<Task> row = getTreeTableRow();
                Task tsk = row.getItem();
                tsk.setStat(c);
            }
        });
```